# iPhone GameKit: Communication with Sandbox - GKErrorDomain Code 3

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, gamekit

Anyone has any experience with GameKit GKErrorDomain Code 3? I receive the error message when I try to upload a score to a leaderboard in the Sandbox. The iOS reference library just says that `Indicates that an error occurred when communicating with Game Centre` The Here is the full error message:

```
Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=3 "The requested operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server." UserInfo=0x75e4eb0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7531e00 "The operation couldn’t be completed. status = 5053", NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server
```

The environment:

- The request is being made from the 4.1 Simulator
- GameKit has authenticated the local player who has logged into the Sandbox
- The leaderboard with the name "Standard" has been created on iTunes connect
- I can browse the web in the simulator

Here is the code I use to upload the score

```
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"Standard"] autorelease];
    scoreReporter.value = 10;
    [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) 
     { 
    if (error != nil) 
         {
             // handle the reporting error
             NSLog(@"An error occured reporting the score");
         }
         else 
         {
             NSLog(@"The score was reported successfully");
         }
     }];
```

Comment: That is pretty much the score from the Apple docs. I have used that successfully. I find that more often than not, errors that occur when communicating with GameCenter are caused by problems on the server side. Suddenly things stop working, and a couple of hours later, everything is fine again.

Comment: I've realized that the initWithCategory parameter should take a fully qualified name, such as com.companyName.productName.leaderboard or com.companyName.leaderboard  ... But still GKErrorDomain Code=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason (which is the reason that was affecting me) for GKDomainError Code 3 is if the Leaderboard Category Id specified in the initWithCategory message when initializing GKScore is incorrectly specified.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to track down if you print out the error.
Etc:

```
NSLog(@"An error occured reporting the score: %@", error);
```